# Questions which are too broad

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It happens a few times in the past, that I just wrote an answer to a question which might be **too broad**, and when I was ready to post, the question was closed.

I think many too broad questions can be answered with a recommendation on how to implement this, but not going into details.

So this is first a call for thinking about it might be an option to let the question open and give the people a roadmap how to do something and second a question for your opinion on this, of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case please use "Reopen" button.

Comment: The problem is, that the question is then not reopened immediately and so I forget this. But you are right :)